# How does the async keyword work with Azure Worker Roles?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm playing with Azure Worker Roles. When calling asynchronous WinRT methods and using the `await` keyword, the service execution is ended. I'm guessing this is because `await` returns control to the caller, which is something up the chain in the service internals. Maybe the caller isn't expecting `Run()` to return control until it is finished executing and assumes the service is completed or faulted?

I'm not sure, does anyone know if `async` is intended to be used with Azure Worker Roles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is exactly correct.

At some point in the call stack, you need to explicitly wait (and block) until the operation is finished, by calling `.Wait()` on the `Task` from an `async` method.

You should probably do this in or near the root `Run()` method.